# Moving two different images with ontouchlistener and a bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I'm doing an android application where I have to move different images. I have done some coding, but the problem is : when I want to move ONE image, the others follow with it. Is it possible to make different an on touch listener for each images on a bitmap??

```
MyBringBackSurface ourSurfaceView, ourSurfaceView2;

float x, y, sX, sY, fX, fY, dX, dY, aniX, aniY, scaledX, scaledY;
Bitmap test;
Bitmap dress, dress2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ourSurfaceView = new MyBringBackSurface(this);
    ourSurfaceView.setOnTouchListener(this);

    x = 0;
    y = 0;
    sX = 0;
    sY = 0;
    fX = 0;
    fY = 0;
    dX = dY = aniX = aniY = scaledX = scaledY = 0;
    dress = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dress);
    dress2 = BitmapFactory
            .decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.dress2);
    test = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.cinderelladoll);

    setContentView(ourSurfaceView);

}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    ourSurfaceView.pause();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();
    ourSurfaceView.resume();

}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    x = event.getX();
    y = event.getY();
    sX = event.getX();
    sY = event.getY();

    return true;
}

public class MyBringBackSurface extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {

    SurfaceHolder ourHolder;
    Thread ourThread = null;
    boolean isRunning = false;
    Bitmap back;

    public MyBringBackSurface(Context context) {
        super(context);
        ourHolder = getHolder();
        back = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                R.drawable.wallpaper);
    }

    public void pause() {
        isRunning = false;
        while (true) {
            try {
                ourThread.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        ourThread = null;
    }

    public void resume() {
        isRunning = true;
        ourThread = new Thread(this);
        ourThread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (isRunning) {
            if (!ourHolder.getSurface().isValid())
                continue;

            Canvas canvas = ourHolder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawRGB(02, 02, 150);
            canvas.drawBitmap(back, 0, 0, null);
            if (x != 0 && y != 0) {
                canvas.drawBitmap(test, 150, 150, null);
                canvas.drawBitmap(dress2, x - (dress2.getWidth() / 2), y
                        - (dress2.getHeight() / 2), null);
                canvas.drawBitmap(dress, x - (dress.getWidth() / 2), y
                        - (dress.getHeight() / 2), null);
            }

            ourHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }

}
```

}

Comment: move images from where to where???

Comment: Just moving object from screen to another position on the screen. Just dragging one image at the time...

Comment: like a collage or something..??

Comment: I just want a picture to move across the screen with my finger. But, the problem is when I move one picture, the others follow. I want them to move independently... I dont know if that makes sense...

Comment: are these pictures that you want to move all in one .png file or are they actually multiple png files that you want to use?

Comment: They are in different png files and I would like to use them all..